# Multiple Linux GUI freezes

Tags: linux, freeze, manjaro

I am working on a Lenovo Thinkpad X250, which I upgraded to 8 GB RAM and a 500GB SSD. I had installed Kubuntu for a while, currently I run Manjaro, but there is also a Windows 7 Partition on the device.

With Kubuntu as well as with the new Manjaro I keep having GUI freezes several times a day. As far as I can tell, it has nothing to do with the actual system load at that time, but since `htop` also freezes I can not be sure. The error appears more often when I have Firefox running.

I have shown my Laptop to a local Linux User Group, who tried to find the soure using `dmesg`, but did not find any problem. Is there a way to narrow down the possible source of this problem?

My GPU is an Intel HD Graphics 5500, apparently the Kernel driver is i915.

Comment: Please share vendor and model of your GPU and the drivers used for it.

Comment: My GPU is an Intel HD Graphics 5500, apparently the Kernel driver is i915.

Comment: Run memtest, from grub. Then run an SSD test (in non-destructive mode). It is easy to break things when you open the machine ( [ESD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge) ).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor
I did not do the upgrade of the hardware myself. It was done by a professional reseller, but still, accidents can happen.
I did the memtest. Ran for about an hour, than responded: 
```*** Pass complete, no errors, press Esc to exit***```
How do I run the SSD test?

Comment: An interesting question. Do a search then ask (as a question).

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but could it have anything to do with the fact, that my files are mostly on my Windows partition (NTFS) which I access from Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that partitioning the main data storage partition as NTFS was causing these problems, since the Linux driver for NTFS is not the most performative. I did this to be able to enter my data form both my Linux and Windows Partition. I now reformatted the entire drive and made the main data storage ext4. Since then the freezes do not occur any more.